# How get the nickname of user in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I using msg.author.name, but it gives me id of user, but i need display name of user. I don't find how to get it, so asking here.

I tried all that was in documentation, and all that i find in google.

Some extra characters to break limit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are you on the rewrite branch? Please provide context.

Answer (score 1):

assuming, that you're refering to a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object, `msg.author.name` should be the name, not the id.
Maybe you can include the relevant code where it apparently doesn't work?